# browser compatibility issue

Tags: html, cross-browser, label

see code below..

```
 <div style="overflow:auto;width:250px;height:75px;border:1px solid #336699;padding-left:5px">
<label style="{width:250px;}"><input type="checkbox" name="wow[]" onclick='highlight_div(this);'> PHP</label><br>
<label style="{width:250px;}"><input type="checkbox" name="wow[]" onclick='highlight_div(this);'> LINUX</label><br>
<label style="{width:250px;}"><input type="checkbox" name="wow[]" onclick='highlight_div(this);'> APACHE</label><br>
<label style="{width:250px;}"><input type="checkbox" name="wow[]" onclick='highlight_div(this);'> MYSQL</label><br>
<label style="{width:250px;}"><input type="checkbox" name="wow[]" onclick='highlight_div(this);'> POSTGRESQL</label><br>
<label style="{width:250px;}"><input type="checkbox" name="wow[]" onclick='highlight_div(this);'>SQLITE</label><br> </div>

<script>
function highlight_div(checkbox_node)
{
    label_node = checkbox_node.parentNode;


    if (checkbox_node.checked)
    {
        label_node.style.backgroundColor='#0a246a';
        label_node.style.color='#fff';
    }
    else
    {
        label_node.style.backgroundColor='#fff';
        label_node.style.color='#000';
    }
}
</script>
```

it is listbox showing entries, where user can select multiple entries..when he clicks an entry, the selected gets highlited by blue color for the entire row of the entry...
this highlighting works only in IE , not IN MOZILLA...In mozilla, its gets highlited partially..
wats the workaround for this...

help please
thanks in aadvance....

Comment: please fix format as some of your tags aren't showing as they are not put in code blocks.

Comment: its taking only first line of my code...how i put entire code here

Comment: select all of it and then click the code button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the different seems to be, that in firefox `<label>` is an inline element, while in i.e. it's a block element (block elements ar basically 100% width with linebreak after).

so the fix is to make labels block level elements via css:

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

and get rid of `<br>`s, since you don't need them anymore, [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/mRxsf/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="overflow:auto;width:250px;height:75px;border:1px solid #336699;padding-left:5px"><label style="{width:250px;}"><input type="checkbox" name="wow[]" onclick='highlight_div(this);'> PHP</label><br><label style="{width:250px;}"><input type="checkbox" name="wow[]" onclick='highlight_div(this);'> LINUX</label><br></div> <script>function highlight_div(checkbox_node){  label_node = checkbox_node.parentNode;   if (checkbox_node.checked){label_node.style.backgroundColor='#0a246a'; label_node.style.color='#fff';} else    {label_node.style.backgroundColor='#fff';label_node.style.color='#000'; }}</script>
```

Comment: don't put answers, edit your question and fix it with this data.

Comment: since you updated the question, delete this answer (since it's not really an answer). Also: I put an answer below, take a look : )

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set curly brakets over style content? - `<label style="{width:250px;}">` ?
You should use `<label style="width:250px;">`